# what is the meaning of $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta?$

Tags: measure-theory

From Rudin book

> $\bf 2.17\ $ **Theorem** $\ $ *Suppose $X$ is a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space. If $\frak M$ and $\mu$ are as described in the statement of Theorem $\it 2.14$, then $\frak M$ and $\mu$ have the following properties:*
>
> $(a)\ \ $ If $E\in\frak M$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is a closed set $F$ and an open set $V$ such that $F\subset E\subset V$ and $\mu(V-F)<\epsilon$.
> $(b)\ \ $ $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on $X$.
> $(c)\ \ $ If $E\in\frak M$, there are sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is an $F_\sigma$, $B$ is a $G_\delta$, $A\subset E\subset B$, and $\mu(B-A)=0.$

**My doubt**: In $(c)$ it is written that  that $A$ is an $F_\sigma$ and $B$ is a $G_{\delta}$

My confusion is about symbolic meaning

what  is the  meaning of $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $F_\sigma$ set is a set that is the countable union of closed sets and a $G_\delta$ set is a set that is the countable intersection of open sets.